# Why is this sentence "I want to tell the answers to my friend" wrong?

Tags: word-in-context, idioms-in-context, semantics

Is there any problem about this sentence? English is not my first language and I'm still learning it. About this sentence, I think the problem is in structure or semantics, but i have my doubts.

That sentence is a literal translation from Portuguese to English and a native English speaker said me that has a error. According to him the correct sentence is "I want to tell my friend the answers."

Comment: Please explain why you are so sure that the sentence is wrong. And which details seem wrong to you. Without that information, it looks like we are going to do your school homework, and that is against the site rules.

Comment: We would usually say, "I want to tell my friend the answers." We might occasionally say, "I want to tell the answers to my friend" if we want to put the focus and emphasis on the friend. It's explained [here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/word-order-structures).

Comment: That is not a school homework, it's just a doubt about english. That sentence is a literal translation from Portuguese to English and a native English speaker said me that has a error. According to him the correct sentence is "I want to tell my friend the answers."

Comment: I'm sorry for my english and making this question sounds like a school homework.

Comment: @Mr.Stan: what you said in the comment is exactly the information that should go together with the question. Please edit the question and copy the content of the comment there.

Comment: @virolino Thanks, I'm going to edit my question.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian Thank you very much, your answer is exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The English verb "tell" has two forms:

> tell (something) to (somebody)

or

> tell (somebody) (something)

Both are correct, and valid grammar.  If the (something) is a long and complex phrase, it might be better to use the second form:

> I want to tell my friend the answer to the third question on the test that we did last Friday.

Likewise, if the (someone) is a long complex phrase, it could be moved later in the sentence. But in your example, in which the (somebody) and (something) are roughly equal, and so both forms are possible and natural